# hazard rate linear function instead of hazard rate lambda( λ)

Tags: survival, hazard

Can we find survival function from any hazard rate linear function? Lets say we do not have hazard rate of y as Lambda( λ) but we have hazard rate of y as a linear function. can we find the survival function of y from hazard rate linear function? For instance we have hazard rate(y)=a+by can we find survival function of y or another functions lets say density function for y? Thank you! 
a=alpha b=beta

Comment: What is y here?  What is lambda?  What do you mean “we do not have hazard rate of y as lambda”?

Comment: you can say  h(x)=a+bx. This is hazard rate function and it is just a linear function. I tried to get survival function from h(x)=a+bx and my result is exp^(-at+btx) which does not sounds right to me. I guess I made a mistake so thats why I asked.

Comment: That’s right if x is a time-independent predictor.  Is it?  Why do you think it sounds wrong?  I still don’t understand what x or lambda are...

Comment: Because my solicitation is wrong and I don't know what I did wrong so that is why I need help.  Correct solicitation  S(x) = exp[-x(a +bx/ 2)] and f(x)=(a+bx) exp[-x(a +bx/ 2)]

Comment: Is x supposed to be time?

Comment: Because my solicitation is wrong and I don't know what I did wrong so that is why I need help. Correct solicitation S(x) = exp[-x(a +bx/ 2)] and f(x)=(a+bx) exp[-x(a +bx/ 2)]. By the way x is x from h(x)=a+bx  and lambda was just an example. I just need to know S(x) and f(x) from h(x) because my path is not right!

Answer (score 4):

I presume that by "hazard rate" you imply the hazard function that is defined as: $$h(t) = \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\mbox{Pr}(t < T < t + \Delta t \mid T > t)}{\Delta t},$$
where $T$ denotes the random variable of the survival times.

Then in the standard setting of a single event (no competing risks, etc.), the survival function $S(t)$ and the hazard function $h(t)$ are related according to the formula: $$S(t) = \exp \Bigl \{ - \int_0^t h(s) \, ds \Bigr \}.$$

Hence, you can plug-in your assumed hazard function, and calculate the integral to get the survival function.